# Visual Studios giving me Dereferencing Null Pointer warning

Tags: c, pointers

I am just trying to use malloc and the code runs fine but visual studios gives me issues with it. Is this how you're supposed to do these things or am I doing something wrong?

The warning shows up right on the line:

```c
chadley->name = "chadley"
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    int age;
    char *name;
} Person;


int main()
{
    Person bradley;
    bradley.name = "bradley";
    bradley.age = 2334444;

    Person *chadley = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    chadley->name = "chadley";
    chadley->age = 234;

    printf("Person object %s of age %d", chadley->name, chadley->age);
}
```

Error Code: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'chadley'

Comment: malloc can return NULL sometimes if you're out of memory.

Comment: Sure it runs fine under normal conditions, but what if you have *literally no memory left?*

Comment: *"It isn't even a null pointer I casted it to a Person pointer!"* First, the cast isn't needed [and shouldn't be there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Second, the statement touches two issues that have *nothing* to do with one another. Casting has *nothing* to do with evaluating a pointer against a value, NULL or otherwise.

Comment: Add something like `if(chadley == NULL) return 1;` between line 16 and 17.

Comment: okay I added an if(chadley) for every line of code that references it and the warning went away. This is the correct way to be making a struct with malloc and setting its members though right?

Comment: @bturner1273 you only need to check if malloc failed once. if it did, just give up and exit.

Comment: Post exact text of warning.

Comment: Are you using a C or C++ compiler?  Different language, different warnings, errors

Comment: c, visual studios just didn't like that I didn't add a null check under malloc

Comment: Still - what is the text of the warning?

Comment: @chux 6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'chadley'

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the verbatim diagnostics message - there should also be a diagnostics code ...

Answer (score 3):

A `Person *` can be a null pointer. It refers to the value, not the type.

If it fails to successfully allocate memory, `malloc` will return a `NULL` value. You should always check the value returned from `malloc` before using it.

You can check that the pointer returned is valid doing something like:

```
Person *chadley = malloc(sizeof(Person));

if (!chadley) {
    /* The allocation failed, don't continue. */
    return 1;
}

chadley->name = "chadley";
chadley->age = 234;
```

Comment: [Lose the cast on `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and you'll probably earn at least one uptick.

Comment: `Person *chadley = malloc(sizeof *chadley);` would be more maintainable.

Comment: @chux why do you say this? is there a difference?

Comment: Are you just saying in case I changed the name of the struct?

Comment: @bturner1273: In case you change it's type, yeah.  Compare `T *p = malloc( sizeof (T))` to `T *p = malloc( sizeof *p )`.  In the first case, if `T` ever changes, you have to make both the declaration and `sizeof` operator match up.  In the second, you only have to worry about the declaration.  It also makes life easier if you have to worry about whether `T` is another pointer type, or a pointer to an array type, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    int age;
    char *name;
} Person;


int main()
{
    Person bradley;
    bradley.name = "bradley";
    bradley.age = 2334444;

    Person *chadley = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if (chadley == NULL) return 1;
    chadley->name = "chadley";
    chadley->age = 234;
    printf("Person object %s of age %d", chadley->name, chadley->age);
}
```

works thank you!